# In my code it said Argument not optional in inputbox VBA

Tags: vba

```
Dim b As Integer
Dim strPet As string
Dim intPet As Integer

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 
If Me.TextBox1.Value = "Admin" Then
    If Me.TextBox2.Value = "1234" Then
strPet = InputBox("What is your pet's name?")
If InputBox.Text = "charlie" Then
intPet = CInt(strPet)
MsgBox "Hello bob you are " & intPet & " years old"
        Else
        MsgBox "Please create an account", vbAbortRetryIgnore
       
End If
End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `InputBox` is a function name. It does not have a `.Text` property. You probably meant `If strPet = "charlie" Then`

Comment: But if `strPet = "charlie"` it cannot be converted to an Integer.  So please explain what you are trying to do, as is this code does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: can you please answer my question the error appears (If InputBox.Text = "charlie" Then) at InputBox I've been trying to find a solution for ever

Comment: ThankYou very much

Answer (score 0):

`InputBox` is a function name. It does not have a `.Text` property. You probably meant

```
If strPet = "charlie" Then
```

Your next issue will be trying to convert "charlie" to an `Integer`.